# how to make overlay navigation bar in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm just learning about front end. i have a problem to make an overlay navigation bar instead of dropdown menu when it reach extra small page. so this is what i've done:

```js
function openNav() {
   document.getElementById("navbarSupportedContent").style.height = "100%";
}
  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("navbarSupportedContent").style.height = "0%";
}
```

```css
#navbarSupportedContent {

   height: 0;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
   overflow-x: hidden;
   transition: 0.5s;
 }

 #overlay-content {

   position: relative;
   top: 25%;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 30px;
 }

 #navbarSupportedContent a {
  
   padding: 8px;   
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 36px;
   color: #818181;
   display: block;
   transition: 0.3s;
 }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" onclick="openNav()">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="overlay-content">
        <li class="nav-item pr-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item pr-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item pr-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

when i try to hit the button when it reach extra small, the overlay goes down but it doesn't reach a hundred percent page and it suddenly goes up again. does anyone can help me ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are mixing up Bootstrap core functions and your customs.

Simply remove the *Collapse* classes of Bootstrap, since you already write your javascript code to achieve what you need.

Add this line of CSS:

```
  @media (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-expand-lg .navbar-toggler {
        display: block;
    }
  }
```

Since Bootstrap 4 Media Queries will hide an element matching that class for a screen bigger than 992px.

And then remove all the *collapse-related* class from your HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" onclick="openNav()">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="overlay-content">
        <li class="nav-item pr-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item pr-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item pr-5">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Here's a live working pen: https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/dyYGobJ

Hope this helps!